# multiple attribute not allowed here

Tags: intellij-idea, file-upload, xhtml

This line of code throws an error in my XHTML file on IntelliJ, but it still works correctly. What is my mistake?

```
<input type="file"  name="file" size="50" multiple="multiple"/>
```

The error says: Attribute multiple is not allowed here

Comment: Check the DTD: https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html. `input` has no `multiple` attribute. It's valid for HTML5, but not for XHTML.

Comment: Alright, so is there any way to have multiple attribute in xhtml?

Comment: @DreamIT - Yes, of course. Use [HTML5 in the XHTML syntax](http://w3c.github.io/html/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml)

Comment: Great! Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solution? On a side note, do you think working with XHTML is worth the hassle, or should I just use the more lenient HTML? I started using it because of the supposed performance improvements and that it kept me in check.

Comment: @DreamIT Performance improvements? I know of no performance improvements of XHTML over HTML. If anything, it's wordier, with the `multiple="multiple"` versus 'multiple` in HTML, making for more bytes per page =- longer download times.

Comment: The advantage of XHTML is that it's less lenient, so that if you've got it working, you'll know that you're doing it right, rather than invoking the browser's error handling routines as is often the case with HTML. This also means that if a XHTML files does what you want to do in one browser, the chances of it working in other browsers is bigger.